# Building a class hierarchy with static const members

Tags: c++, static, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a sensible class hierarchy for a congruential random number generator class (which means that it has 3 integer parameters - *M*, *a*, *b*). I decided that the base class should provide an interface for derived ones (so it should be abstract), and *M*, *a*, *b* should be *static const* in derived  classes (as they are the same throughout a derived class).

As *generate()* function is the same for all congruential random number generators, its definition should be placed inside the base class. The problem is that this function uses all of *M*, *a*, *b*, but these can't be be made *static const*'s in the base class.

To illustrate a problem, a provided one of the possible solutions. However, I'm not fully satisfied with it, as it creates 3 extra *long long* variables for each instance of a derived class, so I wonder if a more elegant design can be proposed.

```
class RandomGenerator{
   protected:
       unsigned int seed;

       const long long int M;
       const long long int a;
       const long long int b;

   public:
       RandomGenerator(unsigned int, long long, long long, long long);

       virtual long double generate()  const = 0;
};

long double RandomGenerator::generate() const{
   static long long prv = seed;

   return (long double) (prv = (a * prv + b) % M) / (M-1);
} 

class RandU : public RandomGenerator {
    private:
       static const long long M = 2147483648LL;
       static const long long a = 65539;
       static const long long b = 0;

   public:
       RandU(unsigned int);

       virtual long double generate() const;
 };


RandU::RandU(unsigned int nseed): RandomGenerator(nseed, M, a, b){}

long double RandU::generate() const{
    return RandomGenerator::generate();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to add a class to the hierarchy:

```
class RandomGenerator {
protected:
  unsigned int seed;

public:
  RandomGenerator(unsigned int, long long, long long, long long);

  virtual long long getM() = 0;
  virtual long long geta() = 0;
  virtual long long getb() = 0;

  virtual long double generate() const;
};


inline long double RandomGenerator::generate() const {
  static long long prv = seed;
  return (long double) (prv = (a * prv + b) % M) / (M-1);
} 

class GeneralRandomGenerator : public RandomGenerator
{
  const long long int M;
  const long long int a;
  const long long int b;
public:
  virtual long long getM() { return M; }
  virtual long long geta() { return a; }
  virtual long long getb() { return b; }
};


class RandU : public RandomGenerator {
private:
  static const long long M = 2147483648LL;
  static const long long a = 65539;
  static const long long b = 0;

public:
  RandU(unsigned int);

  virtual long long getM() { return RandU::M; }
  virtual long long geta() { return RandU::a; }
  virtual long long getb() { return RandU::b; }

  virtual long double generate() const;
};


RandU::RandU(unsigned int nseed): RandomGenerator(nseed, M, a, b){}

inline long double RandU::generate() const {
  return RandomGenerator::generate();
}
```

As you can see, I've derived `GeneralRandomGenerator` from `RandomGenerator`. The former now contains members for `M`, `a` and `b`, while the latter provides pure virtual access functions `getM()`, `geta()` and `getb()`. In the `GeneralRandomGenerator` those access functions are implemented to return the members.

But in `RandU`, which still derived from the highest level, the accessors are defined to return the values of the static members.

This way, the `generate()` function of the highest level can access what it needs through the accessor functions, while the values really come from either static or non-static members, or potentially from somewhere completely different. The advantage clearly is that `RandU` won't take any space for `M`, `a` and `b` because those members don't exist in it.

The *disadvantage* however is that even in `GeneralRandomGenerator` access to `M` etc. is performed by calling a virtual function, which mean poorer performance than what would be possible by coding access to the static members directly.

One way to avoid even that is to do provide the generalised for of `generate()` as a separate function outside the classes and pass `M`, `a` and `b` as arguments:

```
namespace general
{
  inline long double generate(long long a, long long b, long long M) const {
    static long double prv = seed;
    return (prv = (a * prv + b) % M) / (M-1);
  }
}

class GeneralRandomGenerator
{
protected:
  unsigned int seed;

public:
  long long a;
  long long b;
  long long M;

  virtual long double generate() const {
    return general::generate(a,b,M);
  }
};

class RandomU
{
private:
  static long long a;
  static long long b;
  static long long M;
public:
  virtual long double generate() const {
    return general::generate(a,b,M);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that templates is really a better way of doing things here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your construct is OK, it doesn't increase the size of your `RandU` class. 
You can check this is true by using the `sizeof` function:

```
int main() {
    cout << sizeof(RandomGenerator) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(RandU) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This returns

```
32
32
```

You can see the full code here: http://ideone.com/HNqeOC

Comment: Yes, but it means that there are 3 _long long int_ for each instance of a derived class. But I want 3 _long long int_ for all instances, that's why I'm using _static_ variables.